# Find common letters in two Strings (Java)

Tags: java, string, algorithm

The goal is to find common letters in two given Strings `s1` and `s2`.

The string of common signs must be at least two letters long.

#### Input example

```java
String s1 = "BAABBBAABBA";
String s2 = "BBBABBBAA";
```

#### Steps to narrow to the solution

1. Step:

```
s1 = BAA**BBBA**ABBA
s2 = **BBBA**BBBABA

len = 4
```

2. Step:

```
s1 = BAA____A**BBA**
s2 = ____B**BBA**BA

len = 3
```

I'm a beginner and literally struggling with this case 4 hours.
Can someone help me out with this?
Will be great to receive a solution in java.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: 4 hours is nothing. Getting stuck on something and solving it with a lot of effort is the best way to really learn. Where specifically are you stuck? what did you try util now?

Comment: Welcome to SO! This is not a solution-factory. Please read [ask] and post your code attempt as [example]. So we can guide you in the right direction.

Comment: As suggested by @Akchene_ye, here you have a link that may be useful: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/common-characters-n-strings/

Comment: How about `len = 6` with `BA<ABBBAA>BBA` vs `BBB<ABBBAA>`?

Answer (score 1):

Maybe following code helps you. The idea is to create all possible substrings from one String to check if the substring is contained in the other String.

```
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.Set;

public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        String s1 = "BAABBBAABBA";
        String s2 = "BBBABBBAA";

        Set<String> foundSet = new HashSet<>();

        for (int start = 0; start < s1.length() - 1; ++start) {

            for (int end = start + 2; end <= s1.length(); ++end) {
                String subString = s1.substring(start, end);
                if (s2.contains(subString)) {
                    foundSet.add(subString);
                }
            }
        }

        foundSet.forEach(System.out::println);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public class example {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String string1 = "dabdabdab", string2 = "badbadbad";//In this case the result will be a, a, a, and the count will be 3.
        char a,b;
        int count = 0, y = string1.length(), x = 0;
        char[] charArray;
        for (int i = 0; i < string1.length();i++){
            a = string1.charAt(i);
            b = string2.charAt(i);
            if (a == b){
                count++;
            }
        }
        charArray = new char[count];//Just for the array to have the size of the exact common elements of the strings.
        for (int i = 0; i < string1.length();i++){
            a = string1.charAt(i);
            b = string2.charAt(i);
            if (a == b){
                charArray[x] = a;
                x++;
            }
        }
        //Check if the array has the correct amount of elements.
        for (int i = 0; i < charArray.length; i++){
            System.out.print(charArray[i]);
        }
    }
}
```

Enjoy. Comment for more advice.